# why notification bar does not work?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use [primefaces notification Bar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/notificationBar.jsf) for my app. I want it to appear just when an user logs in and gets redirected to a page called main.xhml
I am trying to do it but i don't know why i cant make it appear.

This is a method that is located in a managed bean that does the redirect when clicked the login button at a page called login.xhtml:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityController {

    @EJB
    private IAuthentificationEJB authentificationEJB;

    public String logIn() {
            if (authentificationEJB.saveUserState(email, password)) {
                // Pass a parameter in ussing the URL.(The notification bar will
                // read this parameter)
                return "main.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&login=1";
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Here is the button that the users click to login at a page called login.xhtml

```
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{securityController.logIn()}"/>
```

Here is the page where the users arrive when get loged in(main.xhtml):

```
<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="mainForm">

        <h2>The main page</h2>
        <!-- Why this dont work? -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(function() {
          topBar.show()
           });
         </script>
        <!-- It is possible to change font -->
        <p:notificationBar id="notbar" position="top" widgetVar="topBar" styleClass="top" rendered="#{param.login == '1'}">
            <h:outputText value="Welcome, you are now logged in!"
                style="color:#FFCC00;font-size:36px;" />
        </p:notificationBar>

    </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
```

In the URL i can see login=1, but when the user arrives to main.xhtml the notification bar does not appear.

How can i make it appear? 
Also, do you know how can i make it disappear with a fade effect after 3 seconds?

Comment: can you see any error message related to javascript on your error console in FF ?

Comment: No errors in console in eclipse at all. And not error in browser console either.

Comment: not in server's console, I am talking about [browser's console](http://www.firefoxmastery.com/firefox/introducing-the-firefox-error-console/)

Comment: Can you please change the condition with `rendered="#{param.login == '1'}` *note single quote added covering 1*

Comment: I just added the single quotes around num 1, but still don't work

Comment: Try putting script after the `</p:notificationBar>`

Comment: Yes that worked. Wow :) I don't understand why it works when located after. I just now need to make it disappear in 3 secs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the script after `</p:notificationBar>` as It won't find the DOM when it is loading if you write it before the notification bar.

and to make it disappear it just call `topBar.hide()` with [setTimeOut()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: I try `topBar.hide().delay(2000)` but disappears too fast. Why it doesn't wait 2 seconds?

Comment: Sorry forget that delay stuff use this `setTimeout("topBar.hide()",3000);`